# Is there a standard assignment operator syntax for assigning a value only if it's different?

Tags: swift, operators, variable-assignment

E.g. `a =! b` is `if a != b then { a = b }`

In Swift a property is set even if it is setting the same value. Since I am using Realm Notifications, I do not want to set a property unless it's different. I can do bunches of IF THEN statements, but I'd rather just create my own assignment operator to use.

*EDIT*

I guess my question is twofold now that it seems that `inout` will trigger `willSet/didSet` blocks.

1) My main question 'Is there a standard **assignment operator syntax** for assigning a value only if it's different?' wasn't answered

2) Is there a way in Swift to create this operator without triggering `willSet/didSet`? The whole point is for a Realm Notification to not be triggered.

Comment: Why not just overwrite it if it's the same? Aren't you adding an extra operation every time the value is different?

Comment: Did you create this operator `=!` or are you asking for alternatives

Comment: https://medium.com/@johnsundell/custom-operators-in-swift-284837290f43 and https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/how-to-create-a-custom-operator-like-operator-in-swift-55953c0c0bf2

Comment: @Carpsen90 I did create =!, but I am interested if there is a standard syntax for this scenario. Also `willSet/didSet` should not be triggered if `a == b` already.

Comment: AFAIK the only way to not trigger the property observers is an if condition,

Answer (score 1):

You could use key paths for this, as key paths don't require `inout` declarations.

```
infix operator =!: AssignmentPrecedence

func =!<T, U: Equatable>(lhs: (T, ReferenceWritableKeyPath<T,U>), rhs: U) {
    if lhs.0[keyPath: lhs.1] != rhs {
       lhs.0[keyPath: lhs.1] = rhs
    }
}

func >><T, U: Equatable>(lhs: T, rhs: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<T,U>) -> (T, ReferenceWritableKeyPath<T,U>) {
    return (lhs, rhs)
}
```

The above code creates the operator you described in the question, and also overloads the `>>` one to create an Object+KeyPath pair to pass it to `=!`.

Usage would be somewhere along the following lines:

```
class Person {
    var age: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            print("New age:", age)
        }
    }
}

let person = Person()
person>>\.age =! 4
person>>\.age =! 4
person>>\.age =! 4
person>>\.age =! 5
person>>\.age =! 5
```

As intended the code will print:

```
New age: 4
New age: 5
```

, even if the same value was assigned multiple, consecutive, times.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I'm not sure I'll use this because of the `>>\` requirement takes away from code readability. I am probably stuck using If Then statements for  now.


You have tons of experience here. Do you know why my original questions wasn't even answered and down-voted?

Comment: @TomDaniel yeah, using two operators can affect the readability and understandability of the code, it might be that this can be simplified more to  one operator, however I doubt the result will be more readable. Regarding the downvote on your question not sure about the reasons of the down-voter, maybe he/she downvoted the first revision of the question, which was kinda short.